# Moving average conditional to other column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to do a conditional moving average for a table that contains past properties calendar with their available days, their reservation days and if the days were booked. An example of the table

```
   Date    | ID | Reservation Day | Booked | Conditional 30 MA|
2019-03-30   11      2019-02-26       1
2019-03-29   11      2019-02-26       0
    .         .           .           .
    .         .           .           .
    .         .           .           .
2019-03-20   11      2019-03-06       1
    .         .           .           .
    .         .           .           .
    .         .           .           .
2019-03-01   11      2019-02-26       1
2019-04-31   20      2019-04-26       1
2019-04-29   20      2019-04-26       0
    .         .           .           .
    .         .           .           .
    .         .           .           .
2019-04-20 . 20      2019-03-06       1
    .         .           .           .
    .         .           .           .
    .         .           .           .
2019-04-01   20      2019-03-06       1
```

What I am trying to get is for example. For the property with ID=11 and for the row with date "2019-03-01" I need to get the 30 days ma of the Booked column, but taking as 0 the days which reservation day > to the date of row we are getting the ma. In this case, I ll have to count the day "2019-03-20" as 0 in the average because its reservation day is > than "2019-03-01" and so on. Let say that now we are getting the ma for the date "2019-03-19", now in this case the "2019-03-20" would be consider as 1. I ll have to do this for different ID, so it is a group by moving average. I already have read other question related to this, but they dont address this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you need something like this:

`dataframe.groupby('ID')['booked'].rolling(30).mean()`

You will also have to order the reservation dates for this to work

Comment: but this line wont be taking into account to check if the reservation date > the date, so I wouldnt be able to take as 0 these cases (even when they have a 1 in the table).